# Image file is not created in folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to store image in my folder with path ***`project/public/uploads`***. My `uploadImage` function catch in parameter image, but file is not created.

```
public function uploadImage($image)
{
    $random = Str::random(10);
    if($image == null) { return; }
    $this->removeImage();
    $filename = $random . '.' . $image->extension();
    $image->storeAs('uploads', $filename);
    $this->image = $filename;
    $this->save();
}
```

`dd($image)` show this

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#270 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "korabl_more_zakat_luna_63381_1920x1080.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/tmp"
  filename: "phpfJOzTp"
  basename: "phpfJOzTp"
  pathname: "/tmp/phpfJOzTp"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/tmp/phpfJOzTp"
  aTime: 2020-02-07 18:51:11
  mTime: 2020-02-07 18:51:11
  cTime: 2020-02-07 18:51:11
  inode: 34603072
  size: 425567
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 1000
  group: 1000
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

Maybe it's has a meaning i'm using Linux OS, but my access right tuned for creating files in my project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default my congif file `config/filesystems.php` laravel save my images in `storage/app/uploads`, in config file need to change this

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(), // here was storage_path('app')
        ],
```

And now all images will save in `public/uploads/image_name`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **path** including '**public**' folder as follows: `$image->storeAs('public/uploads', $filename);`, as *store* and *storeAs* methods use '*storage/app*' as reference folder.

One more thing - any reason you don't let Laravel generate unique filename for itself? It's a built in functionality of **[store](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-uploads)** method and you don't have to generate it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (!file_exists('uploads'))
 {
     mkdir('uploads',0777,true);
 }
```